# IFS formula with OR condition inside

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Why is the following formula not working?

```
=IFS($B$29=(OR(1;4;10));8310;$B$29=6;9510;$B$29>0;"")
```

When `$B$29` is `10`, should display `8310`, but becomes the empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or if you really need **`IFS`** solution:

```
=IFS(OR($B$29 = 1  ; 
        $B$29 = 4  ; 
        $B$29 = 10); 8310; 
        $B$29 = 6  ; 9510; 
        $B$29 > 0  ; )
```

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
=IF(OR($B$29 = 1  ; 
       $B$29 = 4  ; 
       $B$29 = 10); 8310; 
 IF(   $B$29 = 6  ; 9510;
 IF(   $B$29 > 0; ; )))
```

---

syntax of **`OR`** needs to be in this format: **`=OR(B29=1; B29=4; B29=10)`**

Comment: I need solution with only one IFS formula. Please also add this solution with IFS: `=IFS(OR(B29=1;B29=4;B29=10);8310;$B$29=6;9510;$B$29>0;"")`. I will accept the solution then.